# Filter category products by quantity - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, filter, quantity

My store allows backorders, so some of the products have quantity of 0.
I want to create a switch on the category page on front-end for "**hide out of stock products**" which filters out products

> if quantity is <= 0 (or shows only products with qty between 1 and 9999999).

Is this possible?

All products are set "**in stock**" so I can't use the in stock / out of stock filter.